# Assist with sumif 7 day average formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I need some help with a `SUMIFS` 7 days spend average formula. The formula I have right now is below and it isn't working.

```
=((SUMIFS('Spend Tracker RAW'!H:H,'Spend Tracker RAW'!C:C,"US",">="&$C$23,'Spend Tracker RAW'!E:E,"<="&$C$24)))/7
```

Here sample table:

| Market | Date | Spend |
| --- | --- | --- |
| US | 10/1/2022 | 7.42 |
| US | 10/1/2022 | 3.13 |
| US | 10/1/2022 | 120.05 |
| US | 10/1/2022 | 116.48 |
| US | 10/1/2022 | 748.41 |
| US | 10/1/2022 | 204.78 |
| US | 10/1/2022 | 46.14 |
| US | 10/1/2022 | 164.99 |
| US | 10/2/2022 | 785.95 |
| US | 10/2/2022 | 289.83 |
| US | 10/2/2022 | 272.40 |
| US | 10/2/2022 | 12.55 |
| US | 10/2/2022 | 1.60 |
| US | 10/2/2022 | 120.89 |
| US | 10/2/2022 | 36.99 |
| US | 10/2/2022 | 71.78 |

Comment: kindly post your data as text. I cannot copy/paste an image into excel.  Also, what do you mean by "*isn't working*"?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld added in the data as text. hope that helps. And by isn't working I mean that I keep getting an N/A error

Comment: There’s a construction problem with your sumifs() arguments.  In SUMIF, there’s a range to be summed, followed any number of range/condition paies.  You’ll *always* have an odd number of arguments.  Your second argument is a range, but that is followed by TWO test conditions: `”US”` and `">="&$C$23`.  That’s not possible.

Comment: @Max so I would first need to have a range thats summed and then add in the conditions to test such as a specific market? i'll give that a shot real quick

Comment: @suh not exactly.  If you do `SUMIF(a,b,c,d,e)' that would mean “sum the value in column A for each row where range (b) matches condition (c), and also range (d) matches condition (e).”  Your sumif arguments are “range, range, condition, condition, range, condition)”.  You can’t apply 2 conditions in a row to one range that way.  After “US”, the next value MUST be a range, followed after by another condition.

Answer (score 0):

You sample data has `8` values for the same date, but your condition is based on dates, so it will result in more than `7` values. Please review your question.

You can use `AVERAGEIFS` for that, there is no need to use `SUMIF` unless you have some constraints not expressed in your question.

Here is the formula in `G2`:

```
=IF(F2="","", AVERAGEIFS($C$2:$C$17,$A$2:$A$17,
  $E$2,$B$2:$B$17,F2))
```

You can expand your formula down to include other dates. Based on the input data: E2 (the market) and the list of dates in `F2` obtained by:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B17, B2:B17<>""))
```

**Note**: Filter by non null dates in case you want to expand the range `B2:B17` and keep the formula consistent. If you cannot use `UNIQUE` or `FILTER` because of your excel version, then:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$17,
 MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($F$1:F1,$B$2:$B$17),0,0),0)),"")
```

and expand it down.

Here is the output

[image: sample excel file]

Comment: FYI, they specifically tagged non-O365 versions and will thus will be unlikely to exploit filter/unique.

Comment: Thanks @Max added a note for non-O365 as an alternative to `UNIQUE`. I didn't pay to much attention to the tags, the question was modifying several times, so I was not sure if they tags were properly added.